# Starting Twisted.internet.reactor in python

Tags: python, twisted

I'm trying to run a spider (written in scrapy framework) to run from a python script instead of a command line tool. Scrapy is written on twisted internet framework which has a reactor which cannot be restarted during the process. I must have stopped it while catching the `spider_closed signal` & `the REACTOR HAS STOPPED`. It gives me following error message:

```
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

My question is "How do I start the `twisted.internet.reactor`?"

I'm not able to run my spider even from the command line tool now.

Comment: Reactor cannot be restarted. The way you go around this is you need a new reactor in a new thread. However, it seems in your situation, you simply want to kill the process that currently has reactor running and then start the process again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to figure out how to restart the reactor, change your code to not *stop* it in the first place.